# Passing multiple parameters within a single parameter to a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The stored procedure only has 1 declared parameter as varchar(max).

I need to pass multiple parameters so I combine them in a string string such as below:

```
"Ref=2211010001165381;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165481;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165581;Src=ONLN;"
```

How can I split the values and assign them in their respective columns?

Below is my current query wherein Column Ref looks good:

```sql
WHILE LEN(@LISTMIXTRD) > 0 BEGIN
        select REPLACE(LEFT(@LISTMIXTRD, CHARINDEX(';Src=', @LISTMIXTRD+';Src=')-1),'Ref=','') as Ref   , LEFT(@LISTMIXTRD, CHARINDEX(';Src=', @LISTMIXTRD+';Src=')-1) as Src   SET @LISTMIXTRD = STUFF(@LISTMIXTRD, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @LISTMIXTRD+','), '')
END
```

Comment: If you could pass the value in a more traditional format, such as JSON, then you would have a much easier time.

Comment: Can you modify the procedure? Presumably you will/have modify anything that passes values anyway to change the argument being passed. You could pass a *table type* parameter with your data ready-to-use or pass a json array of values. Splitting a string however would seem to be the job of [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) assuming you are using a supported version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another option is a conditional aggregation (it may be a little cleaner).

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) ='Ref=2211010001165381;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165481;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165581;Src=ONLN;'

Select Ref = max(case when B.value like 'Ref=%' then substring(B.value,5,250) end)
      ,Src = max(case when B.value like 'Src=%' then substring(B.value,5,250) end)
 From string_split(@S,',') A
 Cross Apply  string_split(A.value,';')  B
 Group By A.value
```

**Results**

```
Ref                 Src
2211010001165381    ONLN
2211010001165481    ONLN
2211010001165581    ONLN
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I really suggest you change the input value to be something SQL Server can handle without a mess of string replacements. JSON or XML would be *far* better.

This solution *attempts* to convert the value to a JSON value, but it's based on your *one* example. If your data is in poorer condition, even more reason to fix the problem.

```sql
DECLARE @YourParameter nvarchar(MAX) = N'"Ref=2211010001165381;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165481;Src=ONLN;,Ref=2211010001165581;Src=ONLN;"';

SELECT OJ.Ref,
       OJ.Src
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourParameter,',') SS
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRIM('"; ' FROM SS.[value])))V(Trimmed)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONCAT('{"',REPLACE(REPLACE(V.Trimmed,'=','":"'),';', '","'),'"}')))J(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(J.JSON)
                 WITH(Ref varchar(20),
                      Src varchar(4)) OJ;
```